# What is the difference between the user `dbo` and the owner of the database stored in sys.databases

Tags: sql-server, security

We recently had a question come up where the user `dbo` in a database had an `sid` that didn't match the `owner_sid` in `sys.databases`.  I understand how the owner of the database is different from members of the role `db_owner` but I had always thought the user `dbo` was the actual owner of the database.  Is that not the case?  And if so are there any real differences between `dbo` and what's in `sys.databases`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I had always thought the user `dbo` was the actual owner of the database.

That is (or at least should be) correct. The name "dbo" of that User never changes, yet the underlying SID does depending on who created the database, or who it was set to be via [sp_changedbowner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql) (up though, and including, SQL Server 2005) or [ALTER AUTHORIZATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql) (starting with SQL Server 2008).

In all three of those cases, the record in `sys.databases` is also changed so that they are kept in sync. However, when restoring a Database, either from another system or from the same Instance but from a DB that was backed-up / detached prior to one of those 2 SQL commands being executed to change the owner, then upon RESTORE or attach, there will be a mismatch between the `owner_sid` column in `sys.databases` and the "dbo" `sid` in `sys.database_principals` in that DB.

As far as I am aware of, the record in `sys.database_principals` in each DB is the *real* owner, and the `owner_sid` column in `sys.databases` is a matter of record-keeping / convenience (similar to denormalization; without `sys.databases` the system would need to make separate queries across all DBs to get that info, each time requested!) and security. One thing it is used for is to identify a potentially harmful / invalid restored / attached DB is those records do not match. Attempting to access SQLCLR Assemblies marked as either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE` won't load if one has chosen to go the less secure route of enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` as that relies upon the "dbo" SID as it needs to match a Login that has either the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` or `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission. And when there is a mismatch in the SID between those two system catalog views, it can't be determined which one to use, and used as a red-flag for there being a potential security issue. In fact, I test for this condition in the installation script for [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=dba_188289) to alert someone to make the appropriate change, just so that they don't have to waste time hunting it down in case SQL Server complains about it at some point.